# regular expression to match cos(0) or sqrt(0)

Tags: regex

I write this regular expression to match cos(0) or sqrt(0) kind of strings why is it not working

```
re.findall("cos|sqrt\([0-9]+\)",'cos(0)')
```

Answer (score 3):

Ah, you forgot parentheses

```
(cos|sqrt)\([0-9]+\)
```

The pipe has the lowest precedence of all operators. Check **Order of Precedence** at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae5bf541.aspx

Comment: +1 for explanation, but don't forget to escape the parentheses around the number.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
re.findall("(cos|sqrt)\([\d]+\)", "cos(0)")
```

Comment: @Bunny: I tested this and it works fine for me. But if you also want to capture the number (rather than just having a match, you didn't specify this), try `re.findall("(cos|sin)\(([\d\.]+)\)", "sin(350.3)")`